# move through string to next upper case character in visual studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, text-editor, camelcasing

When I'm working in xCode I can use the Command-LeftArrow and Command-RightArrow to move to the next word break or upper case character in the source code this is really handy when renaming variable names etc,

e.g. If I have "rightAudioFile" and my cursor is at the start of the word I can press Command-Shift-RightArrow and select/highlight just the "right" part of the string then I could rename/cut/copy/paste just that bit.

In visual studio I can use ctrl-Left and Right arrow to move between word boundaries, which is still very handy (you can do it in the stack overflow editor too) but I would like both sets of functionality.

Any ideas how I can set this up in VS2008?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CodeRush](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/Coding_Assistance/) can do this.

Comment: I own it.  I've found it to be worth its price, and I haven't noticed any performance problems.

Comment: There's an "Express" version that's free, which you can find here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/dd218053.aspx   I don't know whether it has this particular feature in the free version, though.  There's also a trial version you can download from here which definitely has the feature:  http://www.devexpress.com/Downloads/Visual_Studio_Add-in/

Comment: downloaded the evaluation, ill definately use this. whats your favourite trick to use with it?

Comment: The refactoring is the thing I use most.  I usually set it to Control-Shift-R so it's handy.  You'll notice that it has a "Refactor" and a "Code" section; the Refactor section is intended to change the code without changing functionality, whereas the Code section changes functionality: add a constructor, add an inheritor or base class, change a property, etc.  In the most recent version there's automated unit test running; you can run a single test, a class, or a namespace full of tests.

Comment: @Aran Mulholland (and anyone else for that matter) if you have any CodeRush based questions, feel free to contact me (Details available at the bottom of my Community plugin Author page -> http://code.google.com/p/dxcorecommunityplugins/wiki/RoryBecker

Answer (score 1):

Resharper can do it as well, using a feature called CamelHumps

Comment: Anyone know of a package for atom.io to do this?